# Error attempting to create instance of derived class outside base class

Tags: c++, oop

Basically, I just want to know why this doesn't work.

```
//main.cpp

#include "testHeader.h"
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    Car *car1;
    car1 = new Ford;
    car1->foo();
    return 0;
}


//testHeader.h

class Car {
    public:
        Car();
        virtual void foo();
};

//Ford.cpp

#include "testHeader.h"
#include <iostream>

class Ford : Car {
    public:
        Ford();
        void Foo() { std::cout << "I am a Ford";};
};
```

I get 2 errors;

```
error: expected type-specifier before 'Ford'
      car1 = new Ford;
                 ^
error: expected ';' before 'Ford'
```

I've tried googling this for an hour or so, but I haven't been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `Ford` should be in a header file (maybe `Ford.h`) which you `#include` in `main.cpp`. Otherwise `main.cpp` can't see that it even exists.

Make sure you add inclusion guards to your headers, or you might run into trouble later.

You also need to make the inheritance of `Car` public:

```
class Ford : public Car {
```

Comment: So the Ford header file would be exactly the same as the 'testHeader.h' file, except it wouldn't have any 'virtual' keywords in it, and the name of the class would be 'Ford : Car'?

Comment: @PointToPoint Yes. However, I just noticed: you need public inheritance. So it should be `class Ford : public Car`.